# Identifiy IIS 7 using NSIS

Tags: iis-7, nsis

Is there a way to identify the current version of IIS / using [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page)?

I need a way to add some special behaviour to my installer in case of IIS 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our NSIS installer, we check the MajorVersion and MinorVersion DWORD values found under "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp".  This is the way I found others doing it online.

You could do something like:

```
    ClearErrors
    ReadRegDWORD $0 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp" "MajorVersion"
    ReadRegDWORD $1 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp" "MinorVersion"
    IfErrors skip

    IntCmp $0 7 0 skip 0

    // do special IIS stuff here

skip:
```